# How to add summary table of the order on custom Woocommerce thank you page

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

Hi i set up redirect to custom thank you page

```
add_action( 'template_redirect', 'correct_redirect' );

function correct_redirect(){

    /* we need only thank you page */
    if( is_wc_endpoint_url( 'order-received' ) && isset( $_GET['key'] ) ) {
        wp_redirect('https://localhost/test/thank-you-page-test');
        exit;
    }
}
```

Everything working. Question how to add summary table of the order like on default Woocommerce thank you page?
Thank you